# Using Javascript to play sounds on buttons

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I want to use click to play audio I managed to use Javascript for playing one audio but I need for playing different audios on clicking a particular button.

I am able to play first one but the second one is also playing same audio. I am new in Javascript

```js
function play() {
  var audio = document.getElementById("sound1");
  audio.play();
}

function play2() {
  var audio2 = document.getElementById("sound2");
  audio.play();
}
```

```html
<audio id="sound1" src="https://feeds.soundcloud.com/stream/303404685-hopperkremer-w1-1.mp3"></audio>
<audio id="sound2" src="http://feeds.soundcloud.com/stream/303404681-hopperkremer-w4-1.mp3"></audio>


<input type="button" value="play" onclick="play()">
<input type="button" value="play2" onclick="play()">
```

([codepen](https://codepen.io/achaurasia/pen/YEQwBg))

Comment: because the buttons both call `play()` ...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The full content of your question must be **in** your question, not just linked. Links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you. Put the [mcve] **in** the question, ideally using Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button) to make it runnable ([here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-do-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do-tha)). More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Button2 should call `play2()`........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example:

```js
  function play(){
       var audio = document.getElementById("sound1");
       audio.play();
  }


  function play2(){
       var audio2 = document.getElementById("sound2");
       audio2.play();
  }
```

```html
<audio id="sound1" src="https://feeds.soundcloud.com/stream/303404685-hopperkremer-w1-1.mp3"></audio>
<audio id="sound2" src="http://feeds.soundcloud.com/stream/303404681-hopperkremer-w4-1.mp3"></audio>

  
<input type="button" value="play"  onclick="play()">
<input type="button" value="play2"  onclick="play2()">
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this here I have add pause method also for if someone try to play one audio while other audio is playing, currently running audio will pause and new one will play

```js
var audio = new Audio('https://feeds.soundcloud.com/stream/303404685-hopperkremer-w1-1.mp3')

var audio2 = new Audio('http://feeds.soundcloud.com/stream/303404681-hopperkremer-w4-1.mp3')

function play() {
  audio2.pause();

  audio.play();
}

function play2() {
  audio.pause();
  audio2.play();
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="play" onclick="play()">
<input type="button" value="play2" onclick="play2()">
```

Answer (score 0):

Change to this:

```
<input type="button" value="play" onclick="play()">
<input type="button" value="play2" onclick="play2()">
```

Also change `audio.play()` to `audio2.play()`:

```
function play() {
  var audio = document.getElementById("sound1");
  audio.play();
}

function play2() {
  var audio2 = document.getElementById("sound2");
  audio2.play();
}
```

Comment: hi after changing to play2 still not working see https://codepen.io/achaurasia/pen/YEQwBg?editors=1010

Comment: You need to change `audio.play()` to `audio2.play();` in the `play2` function.

Answer (score 0):

`play()` is being called in second button, change it to `play2()`

```
<input type="button" value="play" onclick="play()">
<input type="button" value="play2" onclick="play2()">
```

Comment: Hi after changing it to play 2 it still doesnt work https://codepen.io/achaurasia/pen/YEQwBg?editors=1010